# Why is access to some of my product displays denied for anonymous users?

Tags: commerce

I think I have some database corruption and a number of commerce display nodes have have become access denied for anonymous users. I am not using any access control modules and the problem persists even after allowing anonymous users to bypass content access control. Clearly there is something badly wrong.

I have clear caches etc, to no avail.

What could be causing this and were should I start looking for a fix?

Following the suggestions given in comments, I have tried rebuilding permissions and this does not help.

Comment: There is a "restore access rights" link on the status report, have you tried that already?

Comment: Are you talking about the 'rebuild permissions' link under Node Access Permissions? Yes I have tried this. Although checking again, I now notice that Node Access Permissions are marked as disabled. Surely this is incorrect?

Comment: I meant that one, did not have a status report available at the moment. Status of disabled is correct of there are no other modules regulating node access. Can you also check the roles table if anonymous users have access to nodes and specific product types?

Comment: Ah you did that already... Then I don't know either.

Comment: Last thing i can think of would be wrong caching of access denied pages by some caching layer. Is there any?

Comment: The site is is development and there is no caching that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It`s because product entity was unpublished.
After publishing entity all warks correct.